# Assign new value to double in a for loop after 6 iterations

Tags: java, for-loop, probability

I cant figure out why `x=x-z` gives me the values it does. 
`x` is supposed to decrease its value by `z` every 6th loop, for 1000 loops, making it less probable that `mrnd` (math random) is greater than `poa` (probability of acceptance).

```
int i = 0; 
double y = 0.9;
double x = 1.0;
double z = 0.1;

for (int o = 0; o < 1000; o++) {
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {


        Double random = Math.random();
        Double mrnd = Math.floor(random*100)/100;

        double poa = (x*y);
        System.out.println("randomkalk " + mrnd);
        System.out.println("probability" + poa);

        if (poa < mrnd ) {
            System.out.println("accept change");
        };
        if (poa > mrnd )  {
            System.out.println("deny change");
        }

    }   
    System.out.println(x-z); // This gives the right output if x=x-z is not present
    System.out.println(" nr 6 \n \n ");
    x = x-z; // Gives wrong output 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: You aren't doing something "every 6th iteration". Instead, for each iteration from a 1000, you do 6 additional iterations.

Comment: Also, do you intend to have it so `x` is less than zero for most of your loop? Even if it decreased every 6th iteration from a 1000, that's means it'll be zero after 36th one, and from that point on your `poa` will always be less than `mrnd`.

Comment: "Gives wrong output" - you should tell us what you'd expect and what you get instead. Note that for `x = 1.0` and `z = 0.1` `x = x - z ` (or in short `x -= z`) would result in a negative `x` pretty quickly. Just a guess here: could it be that you actually mean to just use `x *= y` in the outer loop (thus no need for `poa`)? That would decrease `x` by 10% each time but `x` would never become negative.

Comment: Btw, why are you using `Double` here? `Math.random()` and `Math.floor()` return `double` so there's no need for all that (un-)boxing.

Comment: Added a println with o right before 6, and it does run 1000 times only, and every 6th it prints " nr 6"..

Comment: The println at bottom is just for testing purposes now. What im trying to do is decrease x by z (0.1) every 6th iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As M. Prokhorov points out, you're not doing anything every 6th iteration.  You're doing something 6 times every iteration.  Making another loop inside your loop will only add more iterations of *something*; instead, try checking the counter on the outside loop.

```java
int i = 0; 
double y = 0.9;
double x = 1.0;
double z = 0.1;

for (int o = 0; o < 1000; o++) {
    Double random = Math.random();
    Double mrnd = Math.floor(random*100)/100;

    double poa = (x*y);
    System.out.println("randomkalk " + mrnd);
    System.out.println("probability" + poa);

    if (poa < mrnd ) {
        System.out.println("accept change");
    };
    if (poa > mrnd )  {
        System.out.println("deny change");
    }

    if (o % 6 == 5) {
        x = x-z;
    }
}
```

Here, I use the modulus operator to check if we are on the 6th iteration

- 0 % 6 == 0
- 1 % 6 == 1
- 2 % 6 == 2
- 3 % 6 == 3
- 4 % 6 == 4
- 5 % 6 == 5 **decrement**
- 6 % 6 == 0
- 7 % 6 == 1
- 8 % 6 == 2
- 9 % 6 == 3
- 10 % 6 == 4
- 11 % 6 == 5 **decrement**
- 12 % 6 == 0

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to use modulus at an earlier point when i tested, but i guess i must have gotten that wrong. Works as intended now.